# cameraX TextureView preview height is stretched in real device

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm trying to unstrech the height of the preview that cameraX TextureView is showing.

```
PreviewConfig previewConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
                .build();

        Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfig);
```

```
 <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

my configuration was very simple as given above.

Whatever resolution i set it's not working at all in any way.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this

look at this image How bottle got shrink. 
[image]

But i'm getting the output was proper. Only preview was like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer here for more customization
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt

just copy paste these things step by step

declare two constants

```
private double RATIO_4_3_VALUE = 4.0 / 3.0;
private double RATIO_16_9_VALUE = 16.0 / 9.0;
```

create a method to choose aspect ratio based on mobile device

```
public AspectRatio aspectRatio(int width, int height) {

        double previewRatio = Double.valueOf(Math.max(width, height)) / Math.min(width, height);
        if (Math.abs(previewRatio - RATIO_4_3_VALUE) <= Math.abs(previewRatio - RATIO_16_9_VALUE)) {
            return AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3;
        }
        return AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9;
    }
```

inside startCamera method put this exactly in same way

```
private void startCamera() {

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;


        AspectRatio screenAspectRatio = aspectRatio(width, height);
        PreviewConfig previewConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                .build();


        Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfig);
```

This will work 100%

Comment: This is working like charm but. still it was a little stretched i think. Hence i reduce the texture view size itself and it was working like charm.

Comment: @reza_khalafi what's the problem? None of the answers in the stack stays forever. Sometimes because of the latest updates code might fail to work. Just take it as a hint, write your own code and run it.

Comment: Do you know how to perform a zoom operation?

Answer (score 0):

viewFinder.setScaleType(PreviewView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: what is viewFinder in java. not found it.